# How is smart linking performed by the java virtual machine?

Tags: java, jvm

I know that smart linking is the removal of unused bytecode from an application by the vm. How and when is smart linking performed by the virtual machine ?

Comment: As far as I know the JVM doesn't ever remove bytecode, because what would it remove it from?

Comment: bytecode is a set of tokens to be executed by the jvm, I would expect the compiler to delete most unused "bytecode", if the specific platform has processing to do, it would be done by the JIT pass I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, Hotspot JVMs don't employ anything called "smart linking".  According to Google, "smart linking" is a term used in the context of the Jamacia VM project (for example, [here](http://www.aicas.com/jamaica/3.2/doc/html/codesize.html)).  From a brief reading, that JVM translates bytecodes into C and then compiles it.  Anyhow, the link explains what is going on ...

Comment: I don't get the use of this "smart" linking, does it have anything to do with dynamic linking ?

Comment: I don't think so.  Jamaica is supposed to be a JVM with hard real-time characteristics.

Comment: ah okay so smart linking is related to real-time specification and not related to Hotspot ?

Comment: No.  AFAIK, "smart linking" is a term that used only in the context of Jamacia ...as far as I can make out.  Jamacia is a *specific* implementation of RTSJ.  Google doesn't show any association between "smart linking" and any *other* RTSJ implementations.